# Deleting between the tags it is not deleting

Tags: c#, winforms, tags

I have asked on how to delete between values between the tags and i got solution of which i had to modify to meet my needs, but now the problem is it doesn't delete the values between the tags and i debug to see the error but no error was found. when i check the file that is been created i can still see the values inside the tags. please help me

under new button which copies the file

```
            XmlReadMode omode = oDataSet.ReadXml(PathSelection);
            for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string comment = oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][2].ToString();

                string font = DeleteBetween(comment, "[Font]", "[/Font]");
                string datestamp = DeleteBetween(comment, "[DateStamp]", "[/DateStamp]");
                string commentVal = DeleteBetween(comment, "[Comment]", "[/Comment]");

                string[] row = new string[] 
                {
                    oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                    oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    font, 
                    datestamp, 
                    commentVal
                };
                File.Copy(txtInputfile.Text, txtInputfile.Text.Replace("string-en.resx", "string-lan.resx"));
                Gridview_Output.Rows.Add(row);
           }
```

Function

```
     public string DeleteBetween(string STR, string FirstString, string LastString)
    {
        string regularExpressionPattern1 = @"(?:\" + FirstString + @")([^[]+)\[\/" + LastString;
        Regex regex = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
        MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(STR.ToString());
        var val = string.Empty;
        foreach (Match m in collection)
        {
            val = m.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: I see you copy a file. I do not see that you modify the original file or the copy in any way. Why do you expect the copied file to be anything else than a perfect copy?

Comment: that copied file is the one which must have Ouput deleted. file will be copied but delete the values inside. end results must be [font][/font]

Comment: You are not modifying the file in any way in your code. That is your problem.

Comment: how can i modify it?

Comment: I don't know, why do you have a file at all? You seem to modify variables that have nothing to do with the file. Maybe you should write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first. I have a hard time imagining someone to write a correct regex, yet not knowing how to modify a file.